# Supposed Buddhist Scripture Predicting that only through Jesus can Nirvana be reached

Tags: the-buddha

http://bibleprobe.com/buddhatoldofjesus.htm
Hi, I have been examining the similarities between what Jesus and Buddha taught and I came across this site of the above link in which the author claims that they obtained Buddhist scriptures from Wat Phra Sing in ChaingMai province that predict the coming of Jesus and show that it is nearly impossible to gain enough merit to enter heaven or Nirvana. I suspect that this is completely faked but I always try to approach these sorts of things with the possibility that my assumptions could be wrong.If someone has any information on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every few minutes someone confounds their religion's savior's scheduled arrival with Maitreya's.

Comment: Whoever wrote the linked document seems to have no idea of the core of the Buddhist teachings. Trying to find the truth in propaganda material will not help anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Since the Buddha didn't even said that one could reach Nirvana through Him, how could it be possible to reach Nirvana through anyone else? The only people who can help one attain the goal is him/herself:

"I am the owner of my actions, heir to my actions, born of my actions, related through my actions, and have my actions as my arbitrator. Whatever I do, for good or for evil, to that will I fall heir." ~AN5.57~ ( http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.057.than.html )

Answer (score 2):

I found it being discussed or described on (at least) three sites as follows:

- http://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=1121
- http://dhammaprotector.blogspot.fr/2010/02/christian-lie-sutrapridot.html
- http://sdhammika.blogspot.fr/2009/09/buddha-prophesized-jesus.html

In summary, we can surely all agree it's "fake".

I assume that it is relatively modern, not from the time of the historical Buddha.

There are many ways in which it contradicts the teachings of the historical Buddha, which are found in the Pali canon.

Answer (score 1):

Not disputing the validity of the possible fakeness of the sites mentioned, but I would like to introduce the possibility that Jesus and Buddhism are somehow linked. His short history has big gaps where he could have caravaned to India or communicated with Buddhists somewhere along the route.
The reason I think this is worth bringing up is because of the Gospel of Thomas. It could be mistaken for a book of Zen koans and in some places Buddhist text. It may not be a way for those firstly in Buddhism, but for transplants from Christianity, the Gospel of Thomas makes some crossovers to Buddhism and suggests some alternative history of Jesus who came 500 years after Buddha.
http://lifeintegrity.com/Gospel-of-Thomas-Scholars-Version.pdf
Of course studying any other religion could open the mind and instill compassion for the obstacles they face and for the contribution that religion makes to the advancement of human consciousness.

Comment: The catholic church did accidentally make the Buddha a saint. The Amitahba, arguably, is a Zoroasterian look-alike that showed up about the time Sun Gods were in fashion.

Comment: Buddhist remains have been found in Alexandria, and there was trade between Alexandria and Egypt.  Jesus would not have had to travel far to come across Indian or Buddhist ideas.